# AI tool for background change for Mac

Tags: photography, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for software that can use AI to remove backgrounds. Since I am not familiar with Photoshop, I prefer the software to automatically handle image processing.

**Necessary features**

1. No need for professional photo editing skills;
2. compatible with Mac computers;
3. aesthetically pleasing interface;
4. clean background removal

**Non-necessary but welcome features**

1. The function of remove object from photo
2. Not expensive

Comment: Photos on my iPhone can do this so maybe on the Mac too?

Comment: For which platform? Windows? Mac? Linux? Android? Ios? Other?

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in to macOS  [since Ventura, I think, & also iOS since 15.]

Right click an image in Finder > Quick Actions > Remove Background.

It will drop a clean image in the same location as the original, adding 'Background Removed' to the name. It will save as .png even if the input was .jpg, because jpg cannot handle alpha or transparency.